# How to vertically align and evenly distribute two buttons?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align the two buttons to be horizontally centered, and evenly distributed vertically on the browser window like the following photo:

[image]

```css
#buttonArea {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#addButton {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

#eraseButton {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonArea">
  <button id="addButton">ADD</button>
  <button id="eraseButton">ERASE</button>
</div>
```

The buttons are horizontally centered, but I don't know how to vertically align them so they are evenly distributed. (e.g. ADD: 33.33%, ERASE: 66.66%)

How can I align the buttons like my photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `justify-content: space-around` to distribute equal vertical space around each button and `align-items: center` to horizontally align the elements.

Just a side note, `justify-content` applies to the main axis and `align-items` applies to cross axis. Normally, `justify-content` applies to the x-axis since the default value for `flex-direction` is `row`. However, since we used `flex-direction: column`, the main axis is now the y-axis.

```css
#buttonArea {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonArea">
  <button id="addButton">ADD</button>
  <button id="eraseButton">ERASE</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div id="Area">
  <div class="container">
  <button id="addButton">ADD</button>
  <button id="eraseButton">ERASE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#Area {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center
}

addButton, eraseButton{
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block,
}
```

What I am doing is
You need to set the width the height of the page so that you can set the items in place you want.
Then will set the container of button to height: 100% because u want to align horizontally centered, and evenly distributed vertically.

Next most important thing is justify-content: space-around; Since you are using flex I hope you know this

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `position:relative` to the parent `div` and then for the buttons add `position: absolute;` and use the `top: xx %;` property to align it vertically at 33% and 66% of the height.

```css
#buttonArea {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  width: 100%
  position:relative;
  text-align:centre;
}

#addButton {
  display: block;
  top: 33.33%;
  position:absolute;
}

#eraseButton {
  top: 66.66%;
  position:absolute;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonArea">
  <button id="addButton">ADD</button>
  <button id="eraseButton">ERASE</button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Use position:relative and manage the coordinates accordingly